# Get partial errors from NSError

Tags: ios, nserror, cloudkit

When using CloudKit, sometimes the error returned is `PartialFailure`, which may caused by duplicate subscriptions, etc. See example below.

```
<CKError 0x7f8318711520: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); 
"Failed to modify some subscriptions"; uuid = A434B010-7650-4BBA-8A7A-33CD0690FD15; 
container ID = "iCloud.xxx.xxx"; partial errors: { 
EFC65F4A-A595-44A3-A022-323D9CE9B535 = <CKError 0x7f831a007be0: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2032); server message = "subscription is duplicate of '_930081460_AA87A676-DE57-4530-8BB8-7465BF4F4303'"> 
C4913907-28F3-42DB-8455-9966D9084834 = <CKError 0x7f83185cfc20: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2032); server message = "subscription is duplicate of '_930081460_F92FA91D-3E92-4E46-AE59-E912F8871026'"> }>
```

I wish to retrieve these partial errors from the main error object but I don't know how. `NSError` doesn't have a `partialError` property, and it neither has [a key](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-CJBIAHGF) in `userInfo` to retrieve that.

Comment: If your question could be appropriate to Swift or Objective C, chances are it should be tagged with neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting back a straight `NSError`, you are getting back a `CKError`. Looking at the documentation for `CKError`, there is in fact a `CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey` key. That looks like the key that would return a dictionary of CKErrors keyed by item ID if you ask me! The userInfo object should contain that key.

Also documented here

[CloudKit Framework Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html)

Comment: Actually CKError is not a **class**, but just a sub-framework of CloudKit that holds all the relating NSError additions.

Comment: Do you have #import <CloudKit/CloudKit.h> ? I'm seeing autocompletion, Xcode 6 beta 4.

Comment: Good point. The error domain is that CKErrorDomain value but it is simply an NSError type, fair enough.

Comment: `CKError` is a Swift struct and it's exclusive to Swift.

Comment: @Jonny Not sure where you're getting that information from, but the CloudKit Framework is available with full compatibility on either Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: @Acey CloudKit is available for both languages, but if you check the documentation in Xcode, you can see `CKError` is only available for Swift. Basically `CKError` is just a wrapper of `NSError` that contains some convenient computed properties and make APIs more Swifty.

Comment: @Jonny Yes you're right. I need to read more carefully, I had this same conversation 3 years ago just above in the comments apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Two years later, and I still don't think how to access partial errors is particularly well documented.  Thanks to @Acey for putting me on the right path with `CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey`

For those who are struggling, here is an example of how I ended up accessing a partial error in a `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` (Swift 2.2):

```
someZoneSubscriptionOperation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = {(savedSubscriptions: [CKSubscription]?, deletedSubscriptionIDs:[String]?, operationError:NSError?) in

    // check specifically for an error in changing subscriptions to custom zone with specific subscriptionID
    if let partialError = operationError?.userInfo[CKPartialErrorsByItemIDKey]?[subscriptionID] as? ErrorType {
        print(partialError)         // prints partial error for custom zone with `subscriptionID` if it exists
    }
}
```